# Comparing $R(A)$ and $R(A^{1/2})$ for positive operators

Tags: operator-theory

Can you give me a bounded postive (self-adjoint) operator $A$ on a Hilbert space such that $R(A)\not\subset R(A^{1/2})$ where $R(A)$ designates the range of a linear mapping? Is this possible?

Thanks a lot!

Math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible: $A = A^{1/2}\cdot A^{1/2}$, so everything in the range of $A$ is automatically in the range of $A^{1/2}$.

Comment: What about the other way round?

Comment: The other inclusion need not hold. Indeed, let $A$ be the operator of multiplication by $x$ on $L^2([0,1])$. Then $A$ is the multiplication with $\sqrt{x}$, and the function $f(x)=x^{1/2}$ is in the range of $A^{1/2}$, but not of $A$, because $x^{-1/2}$ is not square-integrable.

Comment: Perfect! Cheers Vadim.

Comment: That’s a really cool example

Answer (score 1):

There is no such example.  Note that for any operators $A,B$, we have $R(AB) \subset A$.  Thus, we have $R(A) = R(A^{1/2}A^{1/2}) \subset R(A^{1/2})$.

Comment: What about the other way round?